# Give as a solution every different number in a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I need to do a predicate, `select(ListOfLists, X)` that returns as a solution every different number in a list of lists, starting with the numbers that are alone in a list, for example:

```
select([[1,2,3],[1,2],[4],[3]],X).
```

Would return:

```
X = 4 ; 
X = 3 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 1
```

Order doesn't matter as long as the numbers that are alone in the list are shown first.

To do this, first I coded 2 other predicates, which are:

```
%OrderedList is Lists ordered by size.  
orderListsBySize(Lists, OrderedLists).
```

Example: `orderListsBySize([[1,2],[6],[3,4,5]], L).` ->`L = [[6], [1,2], [3,4,5]]`

And

```
%ListsWithoutX is Lists without the X elements  
removeFromLists(X, Lists, ListsWithoutX).
```

Example: `removeFromLists(1,[[1,2],[3],[4,1,5]],L).` -> `L = [[2],[3],[4,5]]`

Both predicates work.

Then, to do the `select(ListOfLists, X)` predicate, I tried the following:

```
select([[X|[]]|_], X). select(L1,S) :-
    orderListsBySize(L1, [[X|XS]|LS]),
    length(XS, A),
    A == 0,
    select([[X|[]]|M], S),
    removeFromLists(X, [XS|LS], M).  
select([[X|_]|_], X).
```

But it doesn't work.
It's not a hard exercise to do in other languages, the problem is that it's still hard for me to understand how prolog works. I appreaciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Just a syntactic comment: `[X|[]]` is exactly the same as `[X]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with:

```
select2(ListOfLists,Element):-
    length(List,_Len),
    member(List,ListOfLists),
    member(Element,List).
```

Which will return all the answers, but then get stuck in a loop looking for ever bigger lists.
This can be averted using the `:-use_module(library(clpfd)).` and defining a `fd_length/2` which wont keep looking for bigger lists then exist in the list of lists.

```
fd_length(L, N) :-
   N #>= 0,
   fd_length(L, N, 0).

fd_length([], N, N0) :-
   N #= N0.
fd_length([_|L], N, N0) :-
   N1 is N0+1,
   N #>= N1,
   fd_length(L, N, N1).

select(ListOfLists,Element):-
    maplist(length,ListOfLists,Lengths),
    sort(Lengths,SortedLength),
    last(SortedLength,Biggest),
    Biggest #>= Len,
    fd_length(List,Len),
    member(List,ListOfLists),
    member(Element,List).
```

Example Query:

```
?-select([[1,2,3],[1,2],[4],[3]],X).
X = 4
X = 3
X = 1
X = 2
X = 1
X = 2
X = 3
false
```

If you want unique solutions, you could enclose in a `setof/3` and then call `member/2` again.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly.
I needed unique solutions so I used `bagof/3` instead of `setof/3` because I wanted the solutions in the same order as before. 
So I used `bagof/3`, removed duplicates and then member and it worked!